# Why doesn't work my selection in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why such a sample is not working properly?

```
$("body:not(.modal-content)").css({
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(4px)'
    });
```

it is being applied to all without exception. Jquery 1.1 
I do blur all page, except of the modal windows from "Twitter Bootstrap".
Thanks

Comment: Because you're selecting the `body` element, not the descendant elements of the `body`.

Comment: As a rule there's only one `body` element in DOM. If you have more than one - it's time to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blurring the entire body.

Your modal "window" will be a div (or some other element) *inside* the body (it won't replace the body entirely) so it will be blurred.

You will need to restructure your page so that the body has two child elements: the modal "window" and the rest of the content. Then apply the blur effect to the element containing the rest of the content.

```
<body>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="modal-content">...</div>
</body>

$(".content").css({
    '-webkit-filter': 'blur(4px)'
});
```

NB: The experimental `-webkit-` prefix only works on webkit (and possibly not even on new webkit). `filter` is sufficiently standard that you can drop the experimental prefix now.